# Walking distance with pgrouting for several locations

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, distance, pgrouting, isochrone

I'm intending to calculate the walking distance (not the linear distance, but the "real travelled distance") to several locations (e.g. social infrastructure). Thus I will have to create a routable network.

Most implementations I found are based on a single point only. This would be hell of work, so I hoped there is a possible solution to do the calculation at once for a set of multiple points.

I think the way to go would be PostgreSQL and pgrouting with dijkstra, but I'm not sure. My input layer is a point layer with the given locations, then I have OSM data which has to be made routable. What is the best way to achieve getting isochrone or isodistance (travelled distance) maps?

I also took a look at grapphopper, which seems to be great and easy to configure for an isochrone map of a single point, but I didn't find an implementation for a multipoint isochrones case.

Any hints?

Comment: graphhopper does multi-point routes https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=London%20Waterloo%2C%20SE1%208SE%2C%20United%20Kingdom&point=Tower%20Bridge%2C%20SE1%202LY%2C%20London%2C%20United%20Kingdom&point=Trafalgar%20Square%2C%20WC2%2C%20London%2C%20United%20Kingdom&locale=en-US&vehicle=foot&weighting=fastest&elevation=true&use_miles=false&layer=Omniscale

Comment: I know, that is does multipoint routes, but I think it doesn't do isochrones for several locations calculated in one step. I could do the calculation for each point and then merge the isochrone/isodistance polygones, but that isn't my first choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pgRouting you may need a few steps, but the basic function `pgr_drivingDistance` allows to use an array of start points: https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_drivingDistance.html#pgr-drivingdistance

`SELECT * FROM pgr_drivingDistance(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
        array[2,13], 3, equicost:=true
      );`

This will return a list of network nodes with the cost, that is needed to reach each node. You can use other pgRouting functions to create polygons for example: https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_drivingDistance.html#see-also